# upgrade version of an application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios3.0

i want to know what things need to be do in developing the upgrade version of an application (like bundle version) so that if a user download my upgrade version of my application then it update the old version.

i have develop the upgrade version of my app in old version and just changed its version no. I need that data of my old app remains there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All data in the document directory will not be touch when upgrading. All files in the bundle will be copies from the new version.

Comment: do i need to change any thing except bundle version.